# maxlength not working in input type text in cordova android app

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I'm trying to implement an input field in an android cordova 3.5.0 application as follows:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="7" class="form-control" placeholder=" "/>
```

But maxlength does not work at all.

I tried a work around using javascript as follows:

```
function checkTestPressure(txtBox){

    if(txtBox.value.length > 7){
    console.log(" txtBox = "+ txtBox.value.length);
    var str = txtBox.value;
    str = str.substr(0,7);
    txtBox.value = str;
    }
}
```

html as follows:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="7" class="form-control" onkeyup="checkTestPressure(this);" onblur="trimWhiteSpacesForTextBox(this);"  id="testpressure" placeholder=" ">
```

This works at first but if I keep tapping the keys on keyboards after 7 digits the input text field becomes empty and starts to re-populate as i keep pressing the keys.

This is not acceptable and I would want the first 7 characters only and nothing should populate the field no matter how many times I press the keys on the keyboard.

The code above works fine in the browser on the desktop but gives the issue mentioned above when i run in cordova android application.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Solved] This issue is caused due to predictive text feature of android. Turning off predictive text give the required output.

Comment: You can get a hint from [this stackoverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24443007/maxlength-attribute-of-input-in-html-does-not-work-on-htc-one-m7).

Comment: How to disable that? I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 5):

A bit late, but you can use this attributes to complete disable text correction/modification.

```html
<input                                     
       autocomplete="off" 
       autocorrect="off" 
       autocapitalize="off" 
       spellcheck="false">
```

Comment: that works, but is there a way of getting both autocomplete _and_  text length limit?

Comment: Oh, it didn't for me and since I was time-pressed I alternatively set `type=tel` as a quickfix.

Comment: @njzk2 I think is impossibile with HTML only, because i don't think the OS suggest words only with a limited number of chars.